# Correct placement of code within ASP MVC architecture?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have:

UI layer
Business Layer
Data access layer
Common code layer

When I need to, for example, perform string manipulation that is unique to the application and isn’t a candidate for common code. Where would you place this function?

Currently I have it in the controller but is does not feel right.

Answer (score 2):

I would move it out of the controller but keep it within the MVC application, as it sounds like presentation logic.  It could be a helper or maybe an extension method.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to make Common.UI, which will store all common things for `Pressentation Layer` in a separate project. In the future it will help you to switch between different pressentation layers and use same common features.